# Wrong TimeZone identifier in England

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

In England, we use GMT for our timezone in winter and BST in summer. It's currently GMT but when I use this code to get the correct abbreviation it gives me BST:

```
let abbreviation = TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary.filter { $0.value == TimeZone.current.identifier }.keys.first
```

If I print out the `TimeZone.current.identifier` it gives me `Europe/London`. When I print out the `TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary` it gives me this:

> ["MST": "America/Phoenix", "ICT": "Asia/Bangkok", "NZST": "Pacific/Auckland", "CDT": "America/Chicago", "UTC": "UTC", "WEST": "Europe/Lisbon", "HKT": "Asia/Hong_Kong", "CST": "America/Chicago", "PKT": "Asia/Karachi", "BST": "Europe/London", "KST": "Asia/Seoul", "PET": "America/Lima", "SGT": "Asia/Singapore", "GST": "Asia/Dubai", "MDT": "America/Denver", "BRST": "America/Sao_Paulo", "ART": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires", "CET": "Europe/Paris", "AST": "America/Halifax", "NZDT": "Pacific/Auckland", "JST": "Asia/Tokyo", "CEST": "Europe/Paris", "BRT": "America/Sao_Paulo", "HST": "Pacific/Honolulu", "WIT": "Asia/Jakarta", "WET": "Europe/Lisbon", "AKST": "America/Juneau", "NST": "America/St_Johns", "EEST": "Europe/Athens", "CLT": "America/Santiago", "EST": "America/New_York", "PHT": "Asia/Manila", "GMT": "GMT", "CLST": "America/Santiago", "MSD": "Europe/Moscow", "TRT": "Europe/Istanbul", "PDT": "America/Los_Angeles", "COT": "America/Bogota", "PST": "America/Los_Angeles", "IRST": "Asia/Tehran", "MSK": "Europe/Moscow", "IST": "Asia/Kolkata", "NDT": "America/St_Johns", "WAT": "Africa/Lagos", "ADT": "America/Halifax", "BDT": "Asia/Dhaka", "AKDT": "America/Juneau", "CAT": "Africa/Harare", "EAT": "Africa/Addis_Ababa", "EET": "Europe/Athens", "EDT": "America/New_York"]

As you can see, there is a GMT in there but in order to get that, the `TimeZone.current.identifier` must return `GMT` and not `Europe/London`. Is this a bug? How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use GMT as a time zone to get the local time in England.

Comment: @ElTomato What?

Comment: You can't get the currently used abbreviation from that dictionary, it doesn't contain that information. As you can see for most regions it's the same identifier for both DST and non-DST abbreviations.

Comment: @GuyIncognito should `TimeZone.current.abbreviation(for: someDate)` give me the correct abbreviation that adjusts to DST no matter where I am?

Comment: Update: that didn't work properly. It works for england but when I change my timezone to other places it just says GMT+2 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two values `"Europe/London"` since as you said there is abbreviation for winter `GMT` as well as for day light saving summer with abbreviation `BST`. So returning some first key from dictionary won't work since you have no possibility to determine which is suitable for you (at least if you don't want hard-coded solution).

What you are looking for is method `abbreviation()` which returns correct abbreviation for your `TimeZone` **if it knows its identifier** and **you have correct `Locale`**.

And this is what you are maybe confused about. It simply doesn't work for for example `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 3600)`. This is because `GMT+1` simply doesn't identify if it is `BST` for England in summer or e.g. `CET` used for Czech Republic in winter, you just said that it is one hour from `GMT`. You have to create `TimeZone` using `TimeZone(identifier:)` in order to specify identifier.

**But**, user uses his device already has `TimeZone.current` which returns time zone which knows its identifier and he also has `Locale` which knows his abbreviation, so you don't have to worry that user would see something like `GMT+1` for `Europe/London` instead of `BST` or `GMT-8` for `America/Los_Angeles` instead of `PST`

---

To show you how it works for different identifiers and for different seasons I used method `abbreviation(for:)` for given `Date` where 1577836800 representing date in winter and 1595289600 date in summer:

```
TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")?
    .abbreviation(for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1577836800)) // GMT
TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")?
    .abbreviation(for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1595289600)) // BST
TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Prague")?
    .abbreviation(for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1577836800)) // CET
TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Prague")?
    .abbreviation(for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1595289600)) // CEST
```

---

You may also want to use `DateFormatter` in order to format date with abbreviation. In order to do that you want to use characters `aaa`:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d.M.yyyy zzz"

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")
dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1577836800)) // 1.1.2020 GMT
dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1595289600)) // 21.7.2020 BST

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Prague")
dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1577836800)) // 1.1.2020 CET
dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1595289600)) // 21.7.2020 CEST
```

Note that it may not work for other regions. For example if you are in UK, it will format abbreviation for time zone `America/Los_Angeles` as `GMT-8` instead of `PST`.

This you can manually fix by changing formatter's locale:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
```

But as I said. User in most cases has its `Locale` and `TimeZone` by default corresponding to what you may need. So for basic working with `Date()` or `Date() + timeInterval` it should work.

Comment: Deleted my earlier comments. I've just realised, my locale was set to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` which was messing up the time zones. Setting it to Locale.current seems to fix this. Please could you update your answer with some info on locales for future readers, thanks!

Comment: @Tometoyou yes, this is something which I forgot to mention. It's in my answer now. 